# Select categorized items without Javascript

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a single page with the display state of categorized items set depending on user selection.  Ideally, I would like this to be chapter/hash (:target) based, but would also be good with checkboxes driving state.

As an exercise, I am trying to avoid the use of Javascript for this purpose.  It does not appear possible, however, I would love to be proven wrong.

To clarify: this particular use case involves a collection of items on a page, each of which may belong to one or more categories.  The user will select a category, and then all items matching that category will have their `display` state set to `block`.  When one of the categories of an item is not selected, it will be hidden (`display: none`).  For example, assuming you could select a class instead of ID with `:target`, it might look like this:

```
<a href="#category1>Category 1</a>
<a href="#category2>Category 2</a>
<a href="#category3>Category 3</a>

<span class="category1 category2">Item 1</span>
<span class="category2 category3">Item 2</span>
<span class="category3">Item 3</span>
```

and CSS:

```
span {
    display: none;
}
:target {
    display: block;
}
```

(This is easy to do in Javascript, so no need to point that out.)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `<a>` because we don't have css selector for (un)clicking an element. But with checkboxes, we have `:checked`

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="cat1" name="category">Category 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="2" id="cat2" name="category">Category 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="3" id="cat3" name="category">Category 3</label>

<span class="category1 category2">Item 1</span>
<span class="category2 category3">Item 2</span>
<span class="category3">Item 3</span>
```

and CSS

```
#cat1:checked ~ span.category1 { display:block!important; }
#cat2:checked ~ span.category2 { display:block!important; }
#cat3:checked ~ span.category3 { display:block!important; }

span { display:none; }
```

see it live: http://jsfiddle.net/FV2Eq/7/

A little explanation of `~`

*This sibling combinator is similar to X + Y, however, it’s less strict. While an adjacent selector (ul + p) will only select the first element that is immediately preceded by the former selector, this one is more generalized. It will select, referring to our example above, any p elements, as long as they follow a ul.*

So, it means that you have to keep them in the same container, like in the example.

Comment: This is great, but do you think it would be possible to do something like this without knowing the class names ahead of time (ie, dynamic content)?  I'm envisioning creating a fixed number of category-X classes, and just numbering the dynamic content at render-time... but that seems a little ugly.

Comment: I think it's impossible, but you can prepare big enough list before: http://jsfiddle.net/FV2Eq/12/.